# Can't get `fetch()` working in React Native

Tags: react-native

Any idea why I can't get `fetch()` working in React Native? Full code is here on RN Play:
https://rnplay.org/apps/L80w2w

Here's a working ReactJS Fiddle that I'm trying to get working in React Native: https://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/fEsYt/

```
componentDidMount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var queryParams = "fn" + Date.now() + '/';
        var queryUrl = "https://www.reddit.com/reddits.json?jsonp=" + queryParams;

        fetch(queryUrl)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseData => this._handleResponse(responseData.data.children))
          .catch(error => this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            errorMessage: 'Something bad happened - loading navigationItems: \n' + error
          }));
    },

    _handleResponse(results) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });

        if (results.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                navigationItems: results
            });
        } else {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: "Can't find JSON." });
        }
    },
```

Comment: rnplay link is not working, please create a new one in snack.expo.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to call the Reddit using the [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) technique, which is not necessary, as React Native does not impose the Same-Origin security policy  as browsers do.

If you remove the `?jsonp=" + queryParams` parameter from your URL, the requests should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    completed = (id) => {
        var details = {
            'id': id,

        };

        var formBody = [];
        for (var property in details) {
            var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
            var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
            formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
        formBody = formBody.join("&");

        fetch(markcompleted, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: formBody
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson, 'res JSON');
                if (responseJson.status == "success") {
                    console.log(this.state);
                    alert("your todolist is completed!!");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

#change post into get
```

Comment: Please try to explain why and how this code works, so it is easier to understand for everyone who comes across this answer.